# Как происходит округление до копеек при реальных вычислениях финансовых операций в Python?

Tags: python-3.x, округление

Как правильно? Округление надо производить после каждого этапа вычислений или в конце всей цепочки вычислений. К примеру вычисления, где используются значения средних чеков.
Какую библиотеку для этого лучше использовать? И как правильно округлять такое? Я слышал, что есть банковское округление, а простое математическое округление ведет в итоге к большой погрешности. Интересует, как это реализовано в реальных проектах.

Comment: Стандартный round в Python 3 реализует банковское округление. В целом, для денег (вычислений с фиксированной точкой) можно использовать стандартный модуль [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

Comment: Я не в россии, но такая информация регулируется законом и специальными актами, под которое и пишется ПО. После тестирования данное ПО получает лицензирование и как оно работает отображено в документации к нему.